# How to connect to Outpan.com API with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, curl

I am working on a university project in which I need to get some product information out of the database of outpan.com into a string or an array of strings.

I am new to coding, that's why I am needing quite a lot of help still. Does anyone of you know how to send a request & get the answer from a c#-environment (Windows Form Application)?

The description on outpan itself (https://www.outpan.com/developers.php) says to send the call by using HTTPS in curl, but what does it practically mean? Do I need to install extra libraries?

I would be glad, if someone could help me with this problem or provide me with a tutorial on how to make these curl calls to a database starting from a c# environment.

If there are more information needed about my settings, let me know.

Comment: This is really too broad a question.  Forget about *curl*, from .Net you would use the built-in `HttpWebRequest`/`WebRequest `.  What you are calling is called a REST API there are many examples, E.g.: [Calling a rest api with username and password - how to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347055/calling-a-rest-api-with-username-and-password-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outpan API uses Basic HTTP auth, so all the request will need to have a header like:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

In the request. In order to do that with C#, you could do the following:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.outpan.com/v1/products/0796435419035");
var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("-your-api-key-here-:"));
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + encodedString;
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

For a full description of the header, check out the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication. Note that the base64 encoded string can be in the form [username]:[password], but the outpan api docs ( https://www.outpan.com/developers.php ) write that they do not use the password part.

Also see: [Forcing Basic Authentication in WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764577/forcing-basic-authentication-in-webrequest) for a nice method wrapper for this logic.

Comment: I'd like to thank all of  you for your answers. They are way more than I expected. @spike Especially this one helped me to make the code run. Since I needed the output in a "string"-format, I added this to the code:              String responseString;

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(responseString);