# How do I pass Basic Auth to a RESTful service in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How do I call a RESTful service and pass in basic auth. This is username and password along with authorization basic.

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                //var request = new StringContent(messageBody);
                //request.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myadmin:mypassword");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

                //var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, customer);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("url here", customer);
            }
```

Comment: What do you send now? What is server response?

Comment: Curently just pass the object over, but I need to set the basic auth aswell for username and password, which I'm not sure how to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# HttpWebRequest using Basic authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334521/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-using-basic-authentication)

Comment: @Ksib possible....but not a duplicate!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to me. Explain how its different. You want to make a post to a service with basic authentication. Seems the same. I also googled your exact title and got results for what you want to do. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347055/calling-a-rest-api-with-username-and-password-how-to) was the other result

Comment: @ksib that one is a GET, mine is a POST

Comment: You should specify that in your post.

Comment: @Ksib see above in desc

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the username and the password with a colon, encode the value to base64 and then add this value to the Authorization header with "Basic" scheme.

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: Post what you have now (how do you access the username and the password, how do you create the client object etc.)

Comment: I'd say this is fine. You have the header in place, from the looks of it you have constructed it the right way. What is the error that you are receiving?